# Rebus - Exit application from Handle method

Tags: rebus

I'm implementing an enricher pattern (https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/DataEnricher.html) using a command/consumer queue where the consumer is the enricher and publishes the enriched message to a separate endpoint (SQL database in this case). The consumer is running as a HostedService which implements cancellation token.

Because I'm consuming commands from one transport and publishing events to another there is a possibility that the transport I'm publishing to is down while the one I'm consuming from is up. In that case I'd like to log an error and stop my Hosted service. However, I cannot see how that would work since whatever calls the Handle method already handles exceptions, and I cannot access my cancellation token. Does anyone have any ideas?

This is a draft of what I want to do.

```
    public async Task Handle(EditedEventData message)
        {
            var enricher = _enricherFactory.GetEnricher(message);
            object @event = await enricher.EnrichAsync(message);

            var transformers = _transformerFactory.GetTransformers(message);
            var messages = new List<object>();

            foreach (var transformer in transformers)
            {
                messages.AddRange(transformer.Transform(@event, message));
            }

            foreach (var item in messages)
            {
                try
                {
                    await _bus.Publish(item);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogCritical("Publishing event message {@item} failed with error {ex}", item, ex);
                    //how do I exit from here?
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would come up with some kind of application service, e.g. `IApplicationControlService`, which you can configure to be injected into your handlers using whichever IoC container you're using.

It could look somewhat like this:

```cs
public interface IApplicationControlService
{
    void RequestApplicationShutdown();
}
```

and then your code could simply

```cs
public class YourHandler : IHandleMessages<EditedEventData>
{
    readonly IApplicationControlService applicationControlService;

    public YourHandler(IApplicationControlService applicationControlService)
    {
        this.applicationControlService = applicationControlService;
    }

    public async Task Handle(EditedEventData message)
    {
        // (...)

        foreach (var item in messages)
        {
            try
            {
                await _bus.Publish(item);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogCritical("Publishing event message {@item} failed with error {ex}", item, ex);

                applicationControlService.RequestApplicationShutdown();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to request the application be stopped, when an error occurs.

An implementation of `IApplicationControlService` could then be something like

```cs
public class BruteForceApplicationControlService : IApplicationControlService
{
    public void RequestApplicationShutdown()
    {
        Environment.FailFast("you should probably not do THIS ");
    }
}
```

or something more gentle  – the point is, that you will be able to provide a way to request your application to shut down "from the outside", most likely from the place where your application is assembled (i.e. the ["composition root"](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/))